# (Node.js) How to store stdout.pipe into a variable?

Tags: node.js, spawn, node.js-stream

I want to get free -m (linux shell command) and store its result into a variable
by using source code below:

```
 var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
     command  = spawn('free', ['-m']);
 command.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Is there any way to store process.stdout in a variable, please me some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple with `child_process.exec`:

```
var child = require("child_process");
var freeOut;
child.exec("free", ["-m"], function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error, stderr);
    return;
  }
  //stdout and stderr are available here
  freeOut = stdout;
  process.stdout.write(stdout);
});
//Note. Do NOT use freeOut here. exec is async. Can only use in the callback
```

Comment: You mean that I cannot return stdout from child.exec right?, actually I want to make a function that can get memory usage directly like console.log(getload.getmemoryusage());. I am a newbie in Node.js

Comment: In node v0.10 you cannot use a regular function with a return value because that is not async. You must use a callback or a promise or an event emitter due to the asynchronous paradigm node uses. In node v0.11 there's a new `execSync` API you could use to return synchronously.

Comment: I've read a lot that exec is not meant for a lot of data, so a solution to storing a variable with spawn would still be useful. I haven;t found the solution yet.